# Identify the brand & model of this transformer

Tags: transformer, identification, converter

thinking this unmarked component was an AC transformer I fried it while measuring it by supplying it with 220V AC current. It appears that it's a DC to DC converter, probably 2x15V. I need the exact same one, not an equivalent one. Please help me identify the manufacturer and specific model from this photo.
[image]

Comment: What makes you think it is a DC to DC converter, specifically a 2x15V one? What has it come out of? Why can't it be an equivalent part?

Comment: Chop into it and see what's inside. There's not much we'll be able to tell you based on just the dimensions. If it's unmarked, you're pretty much on your own. It sure looks like a transformer to me.

Comment: Also, is it possible you just applied the 220V to the wrong winding (i.e. the output, instead of the input)?

Comment: A friend who has notions of electronics told me it was a DC to DC.
Before that an electronic engineer told me to supply it with 220V and measure it in DC and that it could be a 15 + 15V.
It doesn’t matter what went wrong, now it’s fried and the only way to identify it are the dimensions as they are known from the manufacturer and distributors. I can cut it open but what would it tell ?

Comment: Cutting it open will reveal if it's a transformer or a converter. You said it's burned, no? Then it won't matter if you cut it open or throw it away, curiosity (your reason for asking) will be satisfied. Do note the conditional there. I, for one, agree with Fake Name.

Comment: Ok I cut it open and updated the picture with new measurements.

Comment: You guys told me to cut it but didn't warn me about not damaging the winding, now its resistance can't be measured.

Comment: How did you get on with this? It is about 99.9% liable to be just a transformer. What the input was depends on the circuit. IF it was a power supply transformer with mains in then the primary is probably the two pins on one side and secondary (s) is the 4 pins on the other side. BUT it may have been driven by a high frequency inverter rather than mains directly. Knowing what equipment it came from and circuit if available would help muchly. Even just a photo of where it cvame from would help.

Comment: This would be a lot easier if you told us what it came out of, or posted a schematic - how do you know that you need the exact same one? It's just a transformer, so if you know what voltage is required at the secondary you can easily replace it with a new one (or you can rewind this one)

Comment: Most often a vendor will offer various versions of a product like this with different specifications, all within an identical housing (up to the point where the specs require shifting to a larger/smaller one).  Unless this is a unique exception, precise visual determination will not be possible - you need a marking, measurement, or surrounding circuit requirement.

Comment: @OliGlaser I know what I want and what I'm doing, same as with beeswax capacitors.

Comment: @ChrisStratton you're right, so have you identified the vendor ? cause that's what I came to ask. The measurements I can do them myself. I'll accept any transformer that has the same pin arrangement to fit on the board and that is 30mm thick or less.

Comment: @user2534 - yes, but if what you want is not available then you need to consider alternatives. As Chris points out, it's going to be almost impossible to identify the part based on measurements alone, since this is such a common type of design. If we knew what it came from or the voltages involved, then it's likely a solution that will work just like the original can be found.

Comment: @OliGlaser such a common type of design really ? then surely you can show me one with the same pin spacing and arrangement.

Comment: @use2534 without knowing the electrical specs, matching the mechanical characteristics is pointless.  If you know the electrical requirement, adapting something with a slightly different package would likely be realistic.  But just putting something that's the same physical configuration on the board isn't going to get you anywhere, unless it's your lucky day.

Comment: @ChrisStratton it seems that none of you have any idea where to find one with similar mechanical specs (the thing I came to ask) so you try to make me use one with the same electrical specs but different mechanical ones. Either it's super rare or...

Comment: No, we are trying to point out that you are going to get absolutely nowhere until you have a plausible way to figure out what electrical specs are even required.  Simply getting one that looks the same will not fix it, unless you are very good at rolling dice.

Comment: Open up a catalog listing for parts like this, and you will typically see maybe a hundred individual items each referencing one of only a half dozen mechanical drawings - which is to say that each mechanical drawing is shared by many parts with quite diverse and incompatible electrical specs.

Comment: "No" ? then you _do_ know a transformer with the same mechanical specs but you refuse to tell me until I give you the electrical specs, which as you pointed out won't make any difference to the mechanical specs ? that's nonsense, you better tell me which brand makes the same mechanical specs so I can use that one when I have the electrical specs

Answer (score 1):

This is an AC transformer, other than that it would be hard to figure out its specs without the circuit it came from, especially from a fired one. In the futre it is best to make as many measurements as possible in the circuit before removing it.

Aslo cutting it open may not have made a difference in testintg its resistance. If it was fried you may not have been able to determine its resistance anyway.

Why I believe it is an AC transformer, for a transformer to work, the current in one coil has to somehow make current flow in the other coil and the circuit it's connected to. A DC current in one coil will make a magnetic field on the other coil, but a magnetic field by itself won't drive any electrons around. A CHANGING magnetic field, however, does create an electric force which will accelerate those electrons in the other coil into carrying a current. This process is described by Faraday's law of induction. You get a changing field from an AC current, since the current which makes the field is changing.

**Update**

I'm not sure the diameter of the wires will be too helpful, normally the diameter would indicate how much current it handles (thicker = more.)

However the ratio of the winding of the wire is very helpful. As a last ditch effort you could try to determine how many times the wire is wrapped around on each side. Also, since it seems you are really interested in possibly replacing this (as opposed to just being curious,) you could post some pictures of the device it came from and what the device is and does; and we can probably help you get it working again.

[image]

I looked up a few videos for you about transformers,

1. [Animated transformer video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pYTCy6yruXo&feature=related), this is slow with long pauses but seems informative.
2. [How Transformers Work](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZjwzpoCiF8A)
3. [DIY Build a transformer](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s6NyTprQCBI&feature=related), you possibly could rebuild your transformer.

With this information, plus the incoming voltage of the device, you should be able to calculate the output voltage. This wont be easy, you will have to get a fairly accurate count of the number of windings on each side.

For example if the input side has 100 and the output side has 50, the ration is 2:1, so if the input voltage RMS is 10vAc, then the output should be 5vAc. *Anyone reading this, please correct me if I'm wrong.*

You may also try a distributor like [Mouser](http://mouser.com) and try to find one with the exact dimensions, but my guess is that there will be many different voltages that match that size.

Comment: So what's the visible difference between an AC and a DC transformer ? and a AC/DC ?  From the dimensions its power should be 2.5W. I know something can be deduced from the diameter of the wires but dunno what or how. I contacted a dozen of manufacturers, no luck yet.

Comment: @user2534 a DC/DC transformer will need more then two wires coupled inductively, two sets of wires wrapped together around a core will always be AC.

Comment: @user2534 see my update.

Comment: How many turns is it likely to have ? if a thousand then I won't bother. Also how do I separate the windings from the core ? (I think they are around the centre of an "8")

Comment: @user2534 From the picture I'm sure its thousands. You would have to carefully cut it up. I've never done it myself, so I don't know for sure.

Comment: I tried searching on retail sites but I couldn't even find one with the same pins arrangement.

Comment: I tried to count the number of turns but it was going to be a nightmare, so I determined them using the wire diameter and metal density. [Simulation](http://www.sklaic.info/electronics/transformer/transformer.php) has shown the result to be very accurate.

Comment: @user2534 Just for my knowledge, what is this for that you are putting so much effort into it?

Comment: @GarrettFogerlie I'm trying to replicate and understand a device. My replica must be as faithful as possible for later comparative tests to be relevant.

Comment: @GarrettFogerlie BTW if I have the resistance for each windings, how could I deduce the voltage ratio ?

Comment: @user2534 Its not the resistance, but the number of windings. Take a look at http://www.sayedsaad.com/fundmental/21_TURNS%20AND%20VOLTAGE%20RATIOS%20%20.htm You need to know what the incoming voltage is and the winding ratio or both the primary and secondary.

Comment: Then why did several engineers ask me to measure the resistance ?

Comment: @user2534 you'd have to ask them. I provided you the equations via that link, as you can see resistance isn't a factor.